# Unable to locate package python-gpiozero

Tags: python, apt, gpiozero

I've just run

apt-get update

and

apt-get upgrade

on Raspbian, but when I try

apt-get install python3-gpiozero python-gpiozero

it can't find either package.

Can't find any evidence of needing a non-standard apt-repository. How do I install it?

Comment: If you are willing to also upgarde to Jesse you can do sudo apt-get dist-upgrade then rerun the above.

Comment: ah, thanks Steve Robillard. makes sense. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you used should work according to the Pi Foundation's recent [blog post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/latest-raspbian-update/), however, I tried it and got the same error. I believe doing a dist-upgrade  should solve the problem. To upgrade do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then rerun the command to install gpiozero:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gpiozero python3-gpiozero
```

If that does not work or you want to upgrade to Jessie this [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=121880) contains the necessary steps.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a plan. Only one wrinkle for me - I'm using and old Model B with a 4GB card, not sure it'll all fit. Wish me luck!

Comment: I would probably get another card and start with a download of Jessie which should have the pizero stuff included. It is safer, but it all comes down to how important the current card contents are and your backup strategy.

Comment: Remember that there will be a switch from `sysvinit` to `systemd` by default when you change from Wheezy (or older) to Jessie - this *might* produce some operational differences (especially during start-up) that could surprise you - or, *hopefully*, it will pass you by without any differences.